# Add vertical scroll bar to mat-expansion-panel

Tags: angular-material, accordion, mat-expansion-panel

I'm using [Material Design Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api) to display data in a hierarchical way is illustrated here :

[image]

This the way I implement it so I can show multiple **AREAs** which can contain one or more **TEAMs**

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel
    *ngFor="let area of myAreas; let index = index; first as firstExpansion"
    [expanded]="firstExpansion">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title> TITLE </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent >
      <mat-selection-list #teams [multiple]="false">
        <mat-list-option
          *ngFor="let team of area.teams"
          [value]="team">
          <div accordion-button">
            {{team.displayName}}
          </div>
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

This way I'm able to show all my areas while expanding the first one to show its embedded teams.
Now the problem is how to make that list scrollable without exceeding the height of the space between **Search** block and **Add new area** button like this:

[image]

Comment: have you tried applying overflow auto on the container?